# How can i disable that browser's blue colour effect on a link about to be clicked?

Tags: html, css

[The exact thing i want to remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHqqJ.png)

I want to remove the blue default browser effect over a hovered link, just like the way it is with bootstrap. I tried removing it with a CSS rule but it didn't work

```
<a href="#">Home</a>

a:hover { background: transparent; }
```

Comment: it's a color, not background .. or maybe you are looking for text-decoration or even outline

Comment: Have you tried searching around in internet? Because there are countless articles for this exact thing. [This one](https://css-tricks.com/css-basics-styling-links-like-boss/) is one of the better ones

Comment: yes, it didn't work

Comment: Can you show us what you are trying and getting by creating a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)
This is a simple enough problem and the solutions in the above link should work unless you are missing something out.

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your problem. It inherits the color of the parent.

```css
a { color: inherit; }
```

```html
<a href="#">asa</a>
```